# can't install anything using apt-get Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, dpkg

I get the following error when try to install any package using apt.

```
Setting up openvswitch-testcontroller (2.13.1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'cacert.pem': File exists
dpkg: error processing package openvswitch-testcontroller (--configure):
 installed openvswitch-testcontroller package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openvswitch-testcontroller
```

`$ locate cacert.pem`:
`/etc/openvswitch-testcontroller/cacert.pem`

any solution plz?

Comment: please edit the question and add the output of `locate cacert.pem`.

Comment: Remove `/etc/openvswitch-testcontroller/cacert.pem` first. You probably tried to install it another way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a leftover of a file, the `openvswitch-testcontroller` install script wants to save. You can probably simply delete the leftover, but I'd prefer keeping a backup.

So, to move the current file out of the way, run:

```bsh
sudo mv /etc/openvswitch-testcontroller/cacert.pem{,.bak}
```

Then try again.